# How to specify languages for code snippets to be created by widdershins from OpenAPI spec?

Tags: node.js, openapi, widdershins

I want to use [widdershins](https://github.com/Mermade/widdershins) (a node.js app) to generate [Slate](https://github.com/lord/slate) API docs from [OpenAPI](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification) specifications.

Widdershins has an option to specify the languages it should incorporate when generating example code snippets for the API docs.

All the help I can find on this option is the usage output, which tells me this:

```
widdershins [options] {input-file|url} [[-o] output markdown]

Options:
[...]
  --language_tabs       List of language tabs for code samples using
                        "language[:label[:client]]" format, for example:
                        "javascript:JavaScript:request"                  [array]
[...]
```

But I can't figure out how exactly to use this option. Whatever I try, I just get the same error message:

```
Not enough non-option arguments: got 0, need at least 1
```

I tried:

```
widdershins --language_tabs="shell,ruby" foo.yaml
widdershins --language_tabs "shell,ruby" foo.yaml
widdershins --language_tabs=shell,ruby foo.yaml
widdershins --language_tabs="[shell,ruby]" foo.yaml
widdershins --language_tabs="[{ 'shell': 'Shell' }, { 'ruby': 'Ruby' }]" foo.yaml
```

I also tried this, exactly as given in the usage help:

```
widdershins --language_tabs="javascript:JavaScript:request" foo.yaml
widdershins --language_tabs=javascript:JavaScript:request foo.yaml
```

But even this yields the same error as described above.

When not using the option at all, it works fine:

```
widdershins foo.yaml
```

But then, I get the defaults for the code snippets generated, which happens to not be I want.

Does anyone know how to specify this option properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to specify the option multiple times, for each language that should be considered when generating the snippets. And also, the input file has to be specified *before* the options, contrary to what the usage help output says:

```
widdershins foo.yaml --language_tabs 'python:Python' --language_tabs 'ruby:Ruby'
```

Another possibility, which is more consistent with the other options, is to add a `--` to terminate the options list:

```
widdershins --language_tabs 'python:Python' --language_tabs 'ruby:Ruby' -- foo.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--language_tabs` flag:

```
widdershins --search false --language_tabs 'ruby:Ruby' 'python:Python' --summary swagger.json -o swagger.md
```